# I need JSZip and gzip for my web page, and JSZip has all the ingredients, but hides them in ways I can't crack

Tags: javascript, gzip, jszip, pako

Support for gzip in JavaScript is surprisingly weak. All browsers implement it for supporting the Content-encoding: gzip header, but there is no standard access to the gzip / gunzip function of the browser. So one must use a javascript only approach. There are some old gzip-js libraries around, but they don't seem stream-enabled and 6 years out of maintenance.

Then there is pako, more actively maintained, but that also doesn't seen stream enabled if using their own distribution, so you need to hold the entire binary array and the gzip output in memory. I might be wrong, but that is what I am gathering.

JSZip is a well designed tool and has support for streams "Workers". JSZip uses pako. ZIP entries are DEFLATEd and have a CRC32 checksum just like gzip, only slightly differently organized of course. Just from contemplating the JSZip sources, it looks like it could be easy to expose the gzip compression option of pako into the stream support of JSZip. And if I use both JSZip and also need gzip, why would I want to load pako twice?

I was hoping I could just hack my way through into the internals of JSZip to the underlying Workers and using the pako based "Flate" (i.e., in-flate / de-flate) implementation with the gzip option recognized by pako. Explored it with the Chrome javascript console, but I can't get through. The distributable loadable jszip.js or jszip-min.js are hiding all the internals from access to scripts. I cannot open that box.

So I have been looking at the git hub source code to see if I could build my own jszip.js or jszip-min.js loadable module where I would export more of the internal resources for use in my page, but having been in this for 20 years, UNIX make files, ant, everything, I feel like a complete novice when it comes to these tricks to packaging javascript modules and I see bower and "gruntfiles" which all seem to be related to node.js, which I don't need (only client-side browser) and never worked with, so I have no idea where to start.

Comment: This is too big and too broad to answer here I think, but my first step would be to see i the developer has build instructions. Looks like they do: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/contributing.html

Comment: Right, thank you, kind of silly of me not to have found this page in the docs. With this link I made progress ... will answer my own question when done. The short version is need to install the entire nodejs, npm and many many modules to be able to build the jszip.min.js but I can then export additional resources ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Evert was saying, I should have checked first for the build instructions in the documentation https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/contributing.html.

From that it is clear, first one needs git and makes a local clone. Then one needs to set up the grunt command line, which requires, npm, which comes with nodejs. Once grunt runs, there are other dependencies that need to be npm install-ed. It's the usual little things off and not working, but enough Googling and brute force retrying to get it done.

Now jszip/lib/index.js contains the resource that is finally exported. It is that JSZip object. So just to play with the internal stuff, I could add these to the JSZip object, for example, it already contains:

```
JSZip.external = require("./external");
module.exports = JSZip;
```

and so we can easily add other resources we want to play with:

```
JSZip.flate = require("./flate");
JSZip.DataWorker = require('./stream/DataWorker');
JSZip.DataLengthProbe = require('./stream/DataLengthProbe');
JSZip.Crc32Probe = require('./stream/Crc32Probe');
JSZip.StreamHelper = require('./stream/StreamHelper');
JSZip.pako = require("pako");
```

Now with that, I can create a proof of concept in the Chrome debugger:

```
(new JSZip.StreamHelper(
   (new JSZip.DataWorker(Promise.resolve("Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!")))
      .pipe(new JSZip.DataLengthProbe("uncompressedSize"))
      .pipe(new JSZip.Crc32Probe())
      .pipe(JSZip.flate.compressWorker({}))
      .pipe(new JSZip.DataLengthProbe("compressedSize"))
      .on("end", function(event) { console.log("onEnd: ", this.streamInfo) }), 
   "uint8array", "")
).accumulate(function(data) { console.log("acc: ", data); })
 .then(function(data) { console.log("then: ", data); })
```

and this works. I have been making myself a GZipFileStream with gzip header and trailer, creating everything correctly. I put a jszip/lib/generate/GZipFileWorker.js in as follows:

```
'use strict';

var external = require('../external');
var utils = require('../utils');
var flate = require('../flate');
var GenericWorker = require('../stream/GenericWorker');
var DataWorker = require('../stream/DataWorker');
var StreamHelper = require('../stream/StreamHelper');
var DataLengthProbe = require('../stream/DataLengthProbe');
var Crc32Probe = require('../stream/Crc32Probe');

function GZipFileWorker() {
    GenericWorker.call(this, "GZipFileWorker");
    this.virgin = true;
}
utils.inherits(GZipFileWorker, GenericWorker);

GZipFileWorker.prototype.processChunk = function(chunk) {
    if(this.virgin) {
        this.virgin = false;
        var headerBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(10);
        var headerView = new DataView(headerBuffer);
        headerView.setUint16(0, 0x8b1f, true); // GZip magic
        headerView.setUint8(2, 0x08); // compression algorithm DEFLATE
        headerView.setUint8(3, 0x00); // flags
        // bit 0   FTEXT
        // bit 1   FHCRC
        // bit 2   FEXTRA
        // bit 3   FNAME
        // bit 4   FCOMMENT
        headerView.setUint32(4, (new Date()).getTime()/1000>>>0, true);
        headerView.setUint8(8, 0x00); // no extension headers
        headerView.setUint8(9, 0x03); // OS type UNIX
        this.push({data: new Uint8Array(headerBuffer)});
    }
    this.push(chunk);
};

GZipFileWorker.prototype.flush = function() {
    var trailerBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(8);
    var trailerView = new DataView(trailerBuffer);
    trailerView.setUint32(0, this.streamInfo["crc32"]>>>0, true);
    trailerView.setUint32(4, this.streamInfo["originalSize"]>>>0 & 0xffffffff, true);
    this.push({data: new Uint8Array(trailerBuffer)});
};

exports.gzip = function(data, inputFormat, outputFormat, compressionOptions, onUpdate) {
    var mimeType = data.contentType || data.mimeType || "";
    if(! (data instanceof GenericWorker)) {
        inputFormat = (inputFormat || "").toLowerCase();
        data = new DataWorker(
            utils.prepareContent(data.name || "gzip source",
                                 data,
                                 inputFormat !== "string",
                                 inputFormat === "binarystring",
                                 inputFormat === "base64"));
    }
    return new StreamHelper(
        data
            .pipe(new DataLengthProbe("originalSize"))
            .pipe(new Crc32Probe())
            .pipe(flate.compressWorker( compressionOptions || {} ))
            .pipe(new GZipFileWorker()),
        outputFormat.toLowerCase(), mimeType).accumulate(onUpdate);
};
```

and in jszip/lib/index.js I need just this:

```
var gzip = require("./generate/GZipFileWorker");
JSZip.gzip = gzip.gzip;
```

and this works like that:

```
JSZip.gzip("Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!", "string", "base64", {level: 3}).then(function(result) { console.log(result); })
```

I can paste the result into a UNIX pipe like this:

```
$ echo -n "H4sIAOyR/VsAA/NIzcnJVwjPL8pJUVTwoJADAPCORolNAAAA" |base64 -d |zcat
```

and it correctly returns

```
Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!
```

It can also be used with files:

```
JSZip.gzip(file, "", "Blob").then(function(blob) { 
     xhr.setRequestProperty("Content-encoding", "gzip");
     xhr.send(blob); 
  })
```

and I can send the blob to my web server. I have checked that indeed the large file is processed in chunks.

The only thing I don't like about this is that the final blob is still assembled as one big Blob, so I am assuming it holds all compressed data in memory. It would be better if that Blow was an end-point of that Worker pipeline so that when the xhr.send grabs the data chunk-wise from the Blob, it would consume chunks from the Worker pipeline only then. However, the impact is lessened a lot given that it only holds compressed content, and likely (for me at least) large files would be multi-media files that won't need to be gzip compressed anyway.

I did not write a gunzip function, because frankly, I don't need one and I don't want to make one that fails to properly parse extension headers in the gzip headers. As soon as I have uploaded compressed content to the server (S3 in my case), when I'm fetching it again I assume the browser would do the decompressing for me. I haven't checked that though. If it's becoming a problem I'll come back end edit this answer more.

Here is my fork on github: https://github.com/gschadow/jszip, pull request already entered.